# rbindlist throws error when using lapply, split on a data.table object

Tags: r, function, data.table

Here's the issue in a nutshell.  `sessionInfo` is listed below the problem description to assist with troubleshooting (data.table_1.14.2)

When using `rbindlist()` or even `do.call(rbind, l))`, I'm unable to create an output `data.frame/data.table` .  Sometimes able to get a strange matrix, which seems to be only a vector of a new column I've calculated, but the rest of the `data.table` is lost.  If I build data frames up by hand, I'm able to do so successfully, but not programmatically.  I've used similar logic at work for about 9 months, and for some reason this is not working.  Has anyone else come across this?

I'm able to scope into the `lapply()` and produce individual data frames as desired (according to the split logic, in this case by location), but running the entire `rbind` in any form is failing.

Thanks in advance.  There seems to be a ticket for `data.table`'s `dev` branch [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5444), and I've logged my observation.

```r
# The most troubling
> rbindlist(list(1:3, 4:6))
Error in rbindlist(list(1:3, 4:6)) : 
  Item 1 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list

# The main issue I'm having
> temp_data <- structure(list(location_id = c(75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 80L, 80L, 
+ 80L, 80L), date = structure(c(19144L, 19145L, 19146L, 19147L, 
+ 19144L, 19145L, 19146L, 19147L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
+     cases_cum = c(4289988, 4293027, 4295818, 4298654, 29570762, 
+     29595892, 29621064, 29641606), population = c(8916185.49099959, 
+     8916185.49099959, 8916185.49099959, 8916185.49099959, 66204314.9643178, 
+     66204314.9643178, 66204314.9643178, 66204314.9643178), location_name = c("Austria", 
+     "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "France", "France", "France", 
+     "France")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
+ -8L), sorted = "location_id")

> str(temp_data)
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  8 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ location_id  : int  75 75 75 75 80 80 80 80
 $ date         : IDate, format: "2022-06-01" "2022-06-02" "2022-06-03" "2022-06-04" ...
 $ cases_cum    : num  4289988 4293027 4295818 4298654 29570762 ...
 $ population   : num  8916185 8916185 8916185 8916185 66204315 ...
 $ location_name: chr  "Austria" "Austria" "Austria" "Austria" ...
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "location_id"

> test1 <- 
+   rbindlist(
+     lapply(split(temp_data, temp_data$location_id), function(x) {
+     x <- x[order(x$date),]
+     x$cases_daily <- c(NA,diff(x$cases_cum))
+   }))
Error in rbindlist(lapply(split(temp_data, temp_data$location_id), function(x) { : 
  Item 1 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list

> test1
Error: object 'test1' not found

> test2 <- do.call(rbind,
+   lapply(split(temp_data, temp_data$location_id), function(x) {
+     x <- x[order(x$date)]
+     x$cases_daily <- c(NA,diff(x$cases_cum))
+   })
+ )

> test2
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
75   NA  3039  2791  2836
80   NA 25130 25172 20542

# Scoping in works fine
> x <- temp_data[location_id == 80]
> x <- x[order(x$date)]
> x$cases_daily <- c(NA,diff(x$cases_cum))
> x
   location_id       date cases_cum population location_name cases_daily
1:          80 2022-06-01  29570762   66204315        France          NA
2:          80 2022-06-02  29595892   66204315        France       25130
3:          80 2022-06-03  29621064   66204315        France       25172
4:          80 2022-06-04  29641606   66204315        France       20542
> y <- temp_data[location_id == 75]
> y <- y[order(y$date)]
> y$cases_daily <- c(NA,diff(y$cases_cum))
> y
   location_id       date cases_cum population location_name cases_daily
1:          75 2022-06-01   4289988    8916185       Austria          NA
2:          75 2022-06-02   4293027    8916185       Austria        3039
3:          75 2022-06-03   4295818    8916185       Austria        2791
4:          75 2022-06-04   4298654    8916185       Austria        2836
> rbindlist(list(x,y))
   location_id       date cases_cum population location_name cases_daily
1:          80 2022-06-01  29570762   66204315        France          NA
2:          80 2022-06-02  29595892   66204315        France       25130
3:          80 2022-06-03  29621064   66204315        France       25172
4:          80 2022-06-04  29641606   66204315        France       20542
5:          75 2022-06-01   4289988    8916185       Austria          NA
6:          75 2022-06-02   4293027    8916185       Austria        3039
7:          75 2022-06-03   4295818    8916185       Austria        2791
8:          75 2022-06-04   4298654    8916185       Austria        2836

> test3 <- lapply(split(temp_data, temp_data$location_id), function(x) {
+   x <- x[order(x$date)]
+   x$cases_daily <- c(NA,diff(x$cases_cum))
+ })
> test3
$`75`
[1]   NA 3039 2791 2836

$`80`
[1]    NA 25130 25172 20542

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_gf_lp64.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.8       purrr_0.3.4       readr_2.1.2       tidyr_1.2.0       tibble_3.1.6
 [8] ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.1   data.table_1.14.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You manipulated `x$cases_daily` but forgot to return the whole `x`. Thus, currently the function returns the last manipulated object.

```
test1 <- 
  data.table::rbindlist(
    lapply(split(temp_data, temp_data$location_id), function(x) {
      x <- x[order(x$date),]
      x$cases_daily <- c(NA,diff(x$cases_cum))
      x  ## add this!
    }))

head(test1)
#    location_id       date cases_cum population location_name cases_daily
# 1:          75 2022-06-01   4289988    8916185       Austria          NA
# 2:          75 2022-06-02   4293027    8916185       Austria        3039
# 3:          75 2022-06-03   4295818    8916185       Austria        2791
# 4:          75 2022-06-04   4298654    8916185       Austria        2836
# 5:          80 2022-06-01  29570762   66204315        France          NA
# 6:          80 2022-06-02  29595892   66204315        France       25130
```

Notice, that you may use `by` instead of `lapply(split(.))`.

```
data.table::rbindlist(
  by(temp_data, temp_data$location_id, function(x) {
    x <- x[order(x$date), ]
    x$cases_daily <- c(NA, diff(x$cases_cum))
    x
  }))
```

Comment: Oh dear lord that was a forehead slapper.  Thank you!